# Why can't we access Super Class Properties without calling Super Constructor in the Subclass?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

1. Why can't we access Super Class Properties without calling Super Constructor in the Subclass?

   ```
   // Shape - superclass
   function Shape() {
       this.x = 10;
       this.y = 20;
   }
   // Rectangle - subclass
   function Rectangle() {
       // Shape.call(this);
   }

   // subclass extends superclass
   // inheritance part code
   Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
   Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

   var rect = new Rectangle();

   console.log( rect instanceof Shape);    // true
   console.log(rect.x);    // undefined
   console.log(rect.y);    // undefined
   ```
2. If I call Super Constructor in the Sub Class i can access Super Class properties with Sub Class Object without writing the inheritance code part So does it means we do not need to write that code for achieving inheritance just calling the superclass constructor is enough ? but i observe in this case subclass object rect doesn't considered as `instanceof` Shape so we are not achieving inheritance isn't it?

   ```
   // Shape - superclass
   function Shape() {
       this.x = 10;
       this.y = 20;
   }
   // Rectangle - subclass
   function Rectangle() {
       Shape.call(this);
   }

   // subclass extends superclass
   // inheritance part code
   // Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
   // Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

   var rect = new Rectangle();

   console.log( rect instanceof Shape);    // false
   console.log(rect.x);    // 10
   console.log(rect.y);    // 20
   ```

Comment: If the code in the superclass constructor doesn't run, how would the properties be initialized?

Answer (score 1):

#### Constructor

What you made there is not really a class, you see. You made a function `Shape` and another function `Rectangle`. If you want both the functions to initialize your object, you gotta make sure they are both called upon it. You could even call more constructors on the same object.

What the constructor in JavaScript actually does: When `function` is called with `new` operator, `this` in that `function` will be a new `Object` and `this.prototype` would be same as that function's `prototype`. The object will also be returned at the end of call. So see, it's not the same constructor as in other languages.

#### "Inheritance"

In completely different piece of code, you assigned `Shape.prototype` to `Rectangle.prototype`. Which only means that `Shape.prototype` is going to be next in searched prototype chain if a property is not a found in a `Rectangle` instance or in `Rectangle.prototype`.

How prototypes work is: You want a value named `myObject.x`. If `myObject` does not have such property, `myObject.prototype.x` will be returned. If that does not exist, `myObject.prototype.prototype.x` will be returned. And so on, until it reaches `Object.prototype`. You can also distinguish between property that is really an object's property and an inherited property using [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).